# How to set manually split long rows size on Octave's Terminal Output?

Tags: formatting, output, octave

#### How to set manually slipt long rows size on Octave's Terminal Output?

I am using Octave through Sublime Text output build panel, and octave cannot recognize correctly how many rows it should use to split/to fill up the screen. 
Example, It is currently filling the screen like this:

```
octave:13> rand (2,10)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 6:

  0.75883  0.93290  0.40064  0.43818  0.94958  0.16467
  0.75697  0.51942  0.40031  0.61784  0.92309  0.40201

 Columns 7 through 10:

  0.90174  0.11854  0.72313  0.73326
  0.44672  0.94303  0.56564  0.82150
```

But I want to set 10 columns (`Columns 1 through 10`) instead of `Columns 1 through 6`.

If I disable the **split_long_rows**, never splits.

> Query or set the internal variable that controls whether rows of a
>   matrix may be split when displayed to a terminal window.
>
> If the rows are split, Octave will display the matrix in a series of
>   smaller pieces, each of which can fit within the limits of your
>   terminal width and each set of rows is labeled so that you can easily
>   see which columns are currently being displayed.

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Matrices.html#XREFsplit_005flong_005frows

Comment: so `terminal_size` returns a wrong size when used inside sublime? Do you start Octave without readline support (--no-line-editing?) That would be my guess: no readline

Comment: btw, you can't view 12 columns if your matrix only has 10 columns (I guess all occurrences to 12 should be 10 in your question)

Comment: Yes, `terminal_size` returns a wrong size when used inside sublime. My screen is very larger than 6 columns. And I did not start Octave with --no-line-editing. My command line to run octave is this: `"cmd": ["sh","$packages/Octave/Octave.sh","sistemas.m"],` and `octave -q $1` on the shell script.

Comment: The screen size isn't measured in "columns" but in chars. "My screen is very larger than 6 columns" doesn't mean anything. What does "tput cols" and "tput lines" return if you add it to your Octave.sh?

Comment: It returns 80 and 24. How to fix it? `doesn't mean anything`, it means there are plenty space to show up much more as the application is on fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot to split them like that. The Octave output is just a simple and fast way to debug your program. To print things beautifully as you want to, just to create a function for it and it to print them.

This is a similar example, where a table is printed:

```
...
for i = 2 : 7
    ...
    % https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Basic-Usage-of-Cell-Arrays.html
    results(end+1).vector = { m, gaussLegendreIntegral________, gaussLegendreIntegralErroExato___ };
end

printf( "%20s | %30s | %30s\n", "m", "Gm", "Erro Exato Gm = |Gm - Ie |" )
printf( "%20s | %30s | %30s\n", "--------------------", "------------------------------", "------------------------------" )

numberToStringPrecision = 15;
for i = 1 : numel( results )
    # https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Processing-Data-in-Cell-Arrays.html
    # https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html#XREFnum2str
    printf( "%20s | ", num2str( cell2mat( results(i).vector(1) ), numberToStringPrecision ) )
    printf( "%30s | ", num2str( cell2mat( results(i).vector(2) ), numberToStringPrecision ) )
    printf( "%30s\n" , num2str( cell2mat( results(i).vector(3) ), numberToStringPrecision ) )
end
```

It would generate a output like this:

```
                   m |                             Gm |     Erro Exato Gm = |Gm - Ie |
-------------------- | ------------------------------ | ------------------------------
                   2 |             -0.895879734614027 |              0.104120265385973
                   3 |             -0.947672383858322 |             0.0523276161416784
                   4 |             -0.968535977854582 |             0.0314640221454183
                   5 |             -0.979000992287376 |             0.0209990077126242
                   6 |             -0.984991210262343 |             0.0150087897376568
                   7 |             -0.988738923004894 |             0.0112610769951058
```